# angular-strap aside don't display properly on navbar-fixed-top

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I am using angular-strap aside to display menu which is open from the button on navbar using bootstrap 3. Everything is working properly. However, after I put in navbar-fixed-top class to navbar, it don't display properly.

HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <!-- When navbar-fixed-top class is added in, it causes problem. Without it, everything works fine -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" bs-aside="aside" data-placement="left">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap.aside']);

app.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.aside = {
    "title": "Title",
    "content": "This is the message!"
  };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ceuca0o/

How can I get it works?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add the following at the end of your CSS

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    z-index: auto;
}
```

Setting the navbar-fixed-top gives it an z-index below the overlay. Since the menu is contained within navbar-fixed-top, that too goes below the overlay.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ju4od25z/

---

This will not work in Chrome. The best you can do is

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    z-index: 1041;
}
```

which is 1 + 1040 (the z-index of the overlay) which **will also bring the navbar over the overlay** (thanks boi_echos!)

The better solution would be the one boi_echos provided.

Comment: still not working for me. And look in your fiddle. Its still below the overlay

Comment: @boi_echos - Updated (just in case OP has some CSS rules that rely on the markup heirarchy)! I had checked in IE (the new version) - didn't realize Chrome treated z-indexed elements differently. Cheers!

Comment: I'm still not satisfied. by doing your solution, navbar appears above the dark overlay. Better to do the solution I found(I have an answer below)

Comment: Ah good catch. I didn't notice that. Definitely agree that data-container=body would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to add data-container="body" to append aside to body (just llike the documentation said). I saw the answer [here](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1759)

Comment: Didn't realize I'd recommended your answer but hadn't upvoted. Sorry about that! Cheers!